# Sorting conctacts in alphabatically order in android

Tags: android, sorting, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

Hi am using this code for getting contacts from Android contact list
last parameter in below method i.e `null`

Can anyone tell me how to sort contact list alphabatically? which parameter I passed so I will get desired output:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
```

Comment: you know, it will take less time to take a look into **DOCUMENTATION**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort contact alphabetically using

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Comment: i also need help for select all contact
and unselect all option i dont have idea how to do it should i show my code here can u help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879045/in-android-am-using-multiple-choice-list-for-contact-selection-how-to-select-all

Answer (score 0):

Use `Upper()` as it will work for both lower as well as upper case contact name.

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null,  "upper("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
```